# parsing of generic xml file without knowing the exact namespace

Tags: xml, soap, xml-parsing

I have an issue of parsing a xml response which i receive as the result of SOAP request in a Java application.

The request is serviced and the response is a xml file whose namespace are prone to change from time to time but however tagname which follows the namespace does not change.

For example,  is the tag then 'status' does not change at any cause, only the namespace prefix 'xxx' changes.

So the query : is there anyway of getting that tag value without knowing the namespace('xxx') details??

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

If the namespace URI does not change, but the prefix does, you can just add the URI to your xpaths (for something like /S:Envelope/S:Body/ns1:someContentElement ):

```
/*[namespace-uri()='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' and local-name()='Envelope']/*[namespace-uri()='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' and local-name()='Body']/*[namespace-uri()='http://service.example.com/' and local-name()='someContentElement']
```

Little wordy but will get around a changing namespace prefix